# Entity Framework 5 code first - where is the database created

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am following along [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj193542)! everything works great, the blog names saved and retrieved from the database (assuming) since they are displayed in the console. Yet there I don't find any database created for it in local db nor the sql express on my machine. How to find where is the database created in the code first approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the connection string by using `ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` which will tell you what database you are using.

Comment: Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=EFConsoleApp.SampleContext;Integrate
d Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMU
E but still when I Check in SQL server Object Explorer there is no database by the name of EFConsoleApp.SampleContext

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to localdb and not local SqlExpress ?

Comment: Well from the above connection string it seem its storing it in localdb. Though I checked local sqlExpress and there is no database by such name as well.

Comment: I meant other way around i.e. to make sure that when checking with SSMS you are connecting to localDb and not to the local SqlExpress if you have one...

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem here. My connection string was set to .\SQLEXPRESS and a generated Initial Catalog name, but when I connected to .\SQLEXPRESS using SSMS, nothing showed up.

Using IntelliTrace in VS 2010, I was able to see the ADO.NET command, and in the Autos grid, it showed me the SQL command and the following connection string: Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|(my_context_name_here).mdf. Then, using the Server Explorer I can connect to (localdb) and see the data.

This problem happened because my context was derived from DbContext, but it did not used the base(connectionStringName) constructor (like the UsersContext that comes with the MVC4 template does). Changing that, I can see the database in .\SQLEXPRESS.